# Replacing part of string within cell with string from different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to replace string within a cell with value from the column that is used in the same table .

String says `"your bonus is bonus_score"` and I want to have `'bonus score'` statement replaced with data from `"bonus_score"` column.

Table structure:

```
person_id nvarchar (8), 
first_name nvarchar(100), 
lastname nvarchar(100), 
text nvarchar(max), 
text_modified nvarchar(max), 
bonus_score decimal(10,2)
```

EDIT:
O have wrongly addressed the question: the aim here is to obtain automatic solution that will detect if string within 'text'contains any name of different columns within the table and automatically replace data within.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` and `replace()`:

```
update t
    set text_modified = replace('bonus_score', bonus_score)
    where text_modified like '%bonus_score%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  This replaces the string 'bonus_score' within the text_nvarchar column with the value from the bonus score column.

```
update tTable
set text_modified=replace(text_nvarchar, 'bonus_score', bonus_score);
```